# Как можно держать в выдачи основной домен, а трафик держать на поддомене

Tags: seo

http://zapret-rf.org/script_rkn/js здесь под номером 2 предлагают скрипт для того что бы можно было держать в выдаче основной домен а весь трафик на поддоменах, это делается для того что бы не забанили основной домен. Есть тут эксперты что бы подсказать как это можно сделать саомму? или подобный скрипт готовый?

Answer (score 0):

> как это можно сделать саомму

В данном случае товарищи просто по user-agent выбирают сценарий поведения.

http://i.prntscr.com/sQdCrIXzQZKPQ5oDY3obMw.png

http://i.prntscr.com/czSZ6w7lThmBlxcy2llzKg.png

Это древний-древний способ, который, видимо, начали продавать под соусом лайфхака. Работать (i.e. держать в выдаче основной домен) будет до тех пор, пока бот не поймет, что его нагло обманывают.

> подобный скрипт готовый?

Что-то похожее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802737/redirect-website-from-different-user-agent-in-php

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: А в каком файле php каталога сайта прописывать данный скрипт? Сайт на wordpress прописал в funtions php все работает, но все пересылает на главную страницу, не могу настроить редирект с $1 чтобы перекидывало на ту же страницу но на новом домене [![описание проблемы с редиректом](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtmWb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtmWb.png)

Comment: @Олег https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671589/redirect-user-to-wordpress-category-based-on-user-agent попробуйте здесь посмотреть.